# Accessibility Narrator reads the class name of the selected Item in the ComboBox instead of the DisplayMemberPath value

Tags: wpf, accessibility

Accessibility Narrator reads the class name of the selected Item in the ComboBox instead of the DisplayMemberPath value

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
    private Student _selectedStudents;
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            if (_students == null)
            {
                _students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
                _students.Add(new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "A" });
                _students.Add(new Student() { Id = 2, Name = "B" });
                _students.Add(new Student() { Id = 3, Name = "C" });
            }
            return _students;
        }
    }

    public Student SelectedStudents
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedStudents;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedStudents = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedStudents));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox
        Height="30"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Students"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudents}"/>
```

When I select the first item of the ComboBox Narrator reads the Student class name instead of the name value "A"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by overriding ToString in the model class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name ?? "Student";
    }
}
```